# Could anyone help me get my NETGEAR WNA3100 (Broadcom BCM43231) wireless adapter to work?

Tags: networking, wireless, broadcom, adapter

I have just moved back to Ubuntu from Windows 7 and a few months ago, I bought a NETGEAR WNA3100 wireless adapter because my old adapter had broken. I plugged in my adapter and it doesn't seem to work, I also used the windows 7 drivers for it and tried them on the program "Windows Wireless Drivers" and they don't seem to recognize the device. However I have heard you need XP drivers but I can't seem to find them on the internet nor find them on the CD.

Could anyone help me get my wireless adapter to work? Any help is greatly appreciate.

P.S I do have internet connection though I have to tether my phone to my computer and then connect my phone to my router.

Comment: Which **Ubuntu** version?  11.10, 11.04, 10.10, 10.04 LTS

Comment: What is the output from: **sudo lshw -C network** and **iwconfig**?

Comment: If anyone is looking for an answer in 2016, i had the same issue and followed the steps from https://github.com/jurobystricky/Netgear-A6210 and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem with my WNA3100 and Ubuntu 11.04
After two weeks of trying all suggestions I could find on the net, I succeeded. I hardly know anything about Linux and found it quite simple. You just need the right driver.

Do the following step by step:

- plug in the wna3100
- open the terminal and type: `lsusb`
- hit enter, you should see something like this:

  ```
  Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0846:9020 NetGear, Inc.
  ```
- if the answer is yes go on with the following
- create a folder somewhere you could find it easily (name it wifi driver or so)
- download the driver from here: (just copy the url, paste it in your web browser and hit enter if the link doesn't work)

  http://media.cdn.ubuntu-de.org/forum/attachments/2612284/Broadcom_bcm43xx_USB_32_64bit_v2.tar.gz
- You will get a box that ask to open or save the driver file
- open it with whatever program you use to unzip (or save it somewhere and unzip it from there)
- unzip it to the folder you created in the first step
- right click both `.inf` files, go to tab 'rights' and click on the make file executable box (mine is in dutch so I don't know if the translation is right)
- close that window
- do the same for the `.sys` files
- now open the windows wireless driver program (download it from ubuntu software center if you don't have it)
- browse the `.inf` file with that program and click install.
- never erase the folder where the `.inf` and `.sys` files are found
- pull out the wna3100
- reboot your computer
- plug in the wna3100, when it stops blinking open the network manager.
- You should be able to see your wireless network.
- if yes, then jump up like me and shout yeehaah (or something alike)
- if not, i feel really sorry for you, but somehow this worked for me and my ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: Hans Verboven:
By "windows wireless driver program" I am assuming you mean ndiswrapper? I cannot get it to install at all. Keeps telling me it can't find the package when I know it is there.

Comment: Damn, link 404s.  Was promising, too.

Comment: I think this is the same one: http://media.cdn.ubuntu-de.org/forum/attachments/06/41/2612284-Broadcom_bcm43xx_USB_32_64bit_v2.tar.gz

Comment: Link in answer outdated.

Answer (score 2):

Actually an open source driver has been developed for the Netgear A6210 that also works for the Netgear WNDA3100v3. While I'm not sure which version you have, I know from experience that this driver also works for the v3:

https://github.com/jurobystricky/Netgear-A6210?