# How do I get a Netgear WNDA3100V2 working?

Tags: netgear

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could anyone help me get my NETGEAR WNA3100 (Broadcom BCM43231) wireless adapter to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48563/could-anyone-help-me-get-my-netgear-wna3100-broadcom-bcm43231-wireless-adapter)

I have Ubuntu 11.10 on my desktop.

A month ago I bought Linksys AE1000 adapter,I did not check that it's not working on Ubuntu and because I've lost receipt I'm stuck with it. Last week I bought Netgear adapter and this time I did check and it meant to be plug an play but it was not. I have checked many forums and managed to install software, system does sees adapter but it's not connecting to network.

I have found that it may not like WPA so I have created my own password-letters and digits,no spaces-still nothing.I don't understand why. This is my next attempt with Linux and I'm not with IT background so it takes time and research before I can resolve something but I really want to learn.

I so wish to learn on Ubuntu.One day, I've checked Fedora16 and my old Linksys AE1000 worked without any instalations.

Comment: Jorge I have different issue.I have managed to connect to network when I have disabled password.My security MODE:WPA-PSK,WPA-PSK Encryption:TKIP+AES,WPA-PSK Version:WPA+WPA2 and I have no own password.Not connecting.What do I have to change.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change frequency mode to "b/g". Mode "b" works as well. Modes "g" and "b/g/n" is not connecting to network.