# Cannot get Netgear WNDA 3100v3 wifi dongle to work

Tags: networking, 16.04, wireless, usb, netgear

First, I have read all of the following, and they get close to helping, but I can't comment requesting more help because I don't have enough beans.

- [Netgear WNDA-3100 Wifi adapter driver install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/565417/netgear-wnda-3100-wifi-adapter-driver-install)
- [How to get Netgear A6200 to work on 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/460277/how-to-get-netgear-a6200-to-work-on-14-04)
- [Netgear WNA3100 WIFI adapter; Cannot connect to internet with it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859188/netgear-wna3100-wifi-adapter-cannot-connect-to-internet-with-it) (Not the same device as what I have.)
- [Could anyone help me get my NETGEAR WNA3100 (Broadcom BCM43231) wireless adapter to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48563/could-anyone-help-me-get-my-netgear-wna3100-broadcom-bcm43231-wireless-adapter)

I have gone through the steps of installing the drivers from https://github.com/jurobystricky/Netgear-A6210, but nothing happens.   [Installed drivers for my adapter but its not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786261/installed-drivers-for-my-adapter-but-its-not-working) is the most helpful, but confusing.  Could someone pick up where they left off in the last comments?  They start talking about encryption, but I just need help getting the drivers to work. What info do you need?  My brain hurts from trying to clarify and anticipate questions.

---

lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 0846:9014 NetGear, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 012: ID 1004:6344 LG Electronics, Inc. G2 Android Phone [tethering mode]
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 045e:00db Microsoft Corp. Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 V1.0
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: This is a question for Chili555 or Pilot6...

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: lsusb

Comment: @chili, lsusb added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have gone through the steps of installing the drivers from
>   https://github.com/jurobystricky/Netgear-A6210, but nothing happens.

That driver is the only correct driver I know of for your system. It compiles perfectly on my 16.10 system. It creates a driver `mt7662u_sta`. Does the driver load without error or warning if you load it?

```
sudo modprobe mt7662u_sta
```

NOTE: This is not a complete answer; I will edit it as we gather further diagnostics.

Comment: Here's what the modprobe returns: `modprobe: FATAL: Module mt7662u_sta not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-72-generic
`

Comment: I tried re-installing, but when I plug the dongle back in and restart the manager, I get an internal error.  Do you want the Journal?

Comment: Yes, please. Post it here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Alright, well, it suddenly works.  I didn't change anything on my Ubuntu side, just ran a few things on my Win partition and came back to Ubuntu....No idea what or why, but it's fixed for now.  Thanks for your help! :)