# How to get my wirleless adapter to work with Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: networking, drivers

I’ve  been trying for a couple hours now and I can’t seem to get this to work. I've been searching all over this site and nothing has helped or I’ve tried it and ran into a obstacle. My wireless adapter is connected and is being picked up in the `lsusb` command but not in the wireless internet connecting box. I have tried so hard to install the drivers onto my Ubuntu system but I can’t since I have no internet and I can’t install git or wine or anything because it just says errors for everything I try to download through terminal. My hotspot doesn’t show up either so I can’t use that as a temporary solution either. The only thing that pops up in my network settings is vpn and wired.

- NetGear Wnda 3100v3 adapter.
- IdVendor 0x0846 NetGear, Inc,
- Idproduct 0x9014

The exact error I am getting for install for example:

```
E: Package git has no installation candidate.
```

For basically everything I try to install through terminal.

And other errors such as

```
E: unable to locate package https://github.com/jurobystricky
E: could find any package by glob AND regex (same address)
```

Comment: 4 gigabyte USB, 40 Gigs allocated to Ubuntu from main OS, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980, 512 GB SSD, 1 Terabyte HD, Intel Core i5-6660K CPU 3.50 Gigahertz.

Comment: Open a terminal, and run the command `lsusb -v`. Give us the EXACT manufacturer and complete model string of your wireless hardware. Then search AskUbuntu for that exact model (no others!). Read how others solved the same problem. If you have en error, search for the EXACT error string. If you still cannot solve it, ask about that error. Provide exact output - "says errors for everything I try" tells us nothing. Do not bury facts in the comments - edit your question instead.

Comment: If you have an internet connection, run `sudo apt update` to download the package database. You don't want `yum` - APT is the package manager

Answer (score 0):

How are you going about installing packages? With `apt-get`? This here:

> The exact error I am getting for install for example.
>   E: Package git has no installation candidate.

looks like you need to either fix your `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `sources.list.d` or you need to run `apt-get update` first, to fetch available packages.

The error:

> E: unable to locate package https://github.com/jurobystricky E: could find any package by glob AND regex (same address)

looks very suspicious to me. Never seen anything like that. Are you doing something like this: `apt-get install https://github.com/jurobystricky`. If you are, then that's not the way apt-get works. With apt-get you can only install packages that are available. You can get the list of available packages like this: https://superuser.com/questions/408082/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-available-i-e-uninstalled-packages-in-debian

Comment: Well I can’t even get a list of available packages because it won’t let me install yum, dcntrl, or anything on that list anyway.

Comment: did you follow the instructions here: https://github.com/jurobystricky/Netgear-A6210 ? What was the result of you following those instructions? Evidently, in order to follow those instructions, you will need to be able to copy data onto your system. F.ex. by using a USB stick or so. Yours is the same question as this one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/903770/cannot-get-netgear-wnda-3100v3-wifi-dongle-to-work

Comment: Also this: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2291817&p=13486852#post13486852